# Determining name for family relationship that involves a step daughter?

Tags: kinship-terminology

My grandma had 3 kids. Her daughter Sally is my Aunt. She has a step daughter. Her step daughter has a daughter. My Aunt Sally is her Grandmother. What does that make us?

Answer (score 3):

I just fed your information into the [Steve Morse's Relationship Calculator](http://stevemorse.org/relation/calculator.html) in this order:

1. parent
2. sister
3. husband
4. daughter
5. daughter

and it returned that your parent's sister's husband's daughter's daughter is to you a

> ???  (non-blood relative)

If you ignore the "husband" that led to the step then you get (as @TomH said)

> 1st cousin once removed  (blood relative)

If you really want a label for the non-blood relationship between you, then I think the following would be as good as any:

> step 1st cousins once removed

Answer (score 2):

Well ignoring the "step" aspect you would be first cousins once removed. See [How to determine relationship with a cousin?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/218/how-do-i-determine-a-relationship-with-a-cousin) for details of how to calculate cousin relationships.